# remove tooltips on bootstrap-select inputs

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have various bootstrap-select inputs on the page.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="OfferingId" class="font-weight-bold"></label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OfferingId, Model.OfferingsSelectList, new
{
multiple = "false",
@id="offeringselect",
@data_max_options = "1",
@show_tick = "true",
@class = "selectpicker",
@title = "-Select Offering-",
@data_live_search = "true",
@data_selected_text_format = "count > 8",
@data_width = "100%"
})
</div>
```

When mouseover these inputs, a tooltip appears, and the attribute **aria-describedby="ui-id-61"** appears in the button for the bootstrap-select input

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light bs-placeholder" data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-1" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" data-id="offeringselect" title="-Select Offering-" aria-describedby="ui-id-61"><div class="filter-option">
    <div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">-Select Offering-</div></div> </div>
</button>
```

The tooltip looks like this:

```
 <div role="tooltip" id="ui-id-68" class="ui-tooltip ui-corner-all ui-widget-shadow ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="top: 297.723px; left: 572.111px;"><div class="ui-tooltip-content">-Select Offering-</div></div>
```

I need these tooltips exclusive to bootstrap-select to be removed without removing other tooltips in the page.  How may I do this?

When I try to use tooltip('disable'), I get an error.

```
$(document).on('focus mouseover', '.dropdown-toggle', function () {
    $('.selectpicker').tooltip('disable');
})

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'
at Function.error (jquery.min.js:2:2589)
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js:6:5615)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:2976)
at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1454)
at t.fn.<computed> [as tooltip] (jquery-ui.min.js:6:5357)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (tags.js:1192:28)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43090)
at v.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41074)
```